# Write in a QML TableView from QtQuick

Tags: qt, qml

I have to make a integration between Qt and QML, I've designed an easy window with a TableView in QML and I would like to fill it from C++ code, but I've no idea of how to do this, I just have a week working with Qt. 
This is my code for the QML window but I need help to know how to fill it. Also I'll like to know how to print information in a Qml screen from Qt, like a process status, and make it auto scrolleable. I think the idea is mostly the same, how to print information in a QML object.
Thanks

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0

Window {
    id: winparent
    visible: true
    color: "gray"
    width: 700
    height: 500

    Rectangle{
        color: "lightblue"

        ToolBar {
            id: toolbar
            width: winparent.width
            height: 120

            Text {
                id: title
                x: 20
                y: 20
                text: "Book Searching"
                color: "darkblue"
                font.pixelSize: 30
        //        font{family: 'Courier'; pixelSize: 20; bold: true; capitalization: Font.SmallCaps;}
            }  // title

            CheckBox {
                id: enabledCheck
                text: "Enabled"
                checked: true
                anchors.right: parent.right
                y: 80
    //            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
        }

        ListModel {
           id: libraryModel
//               ListElement{ title: "A Masterpiece" ; author: "Gabriel" }
//               ListElement{ title: "Brilliance"    ; author: "Jens" }
//               ListElement{ title: "Outstanding"   ; author: "Frederik" }
        } // libraryModel

        TableView {
            x: 20
            y: 170
            width: 660
            height: 200
            enabled: enabledCheck.checked

            TableViewColumn{ role: "title"  ; title: "Title" ; width: 150 ;resizable: false ; movable: false }
            TableViewColumn{ role: "author" ; title: "Author" ; width: 150 ;resizable: false ; movable: false }
            TableViewColumn{ role: "year" ; title: "Year" ; width: 150 ;resizable: false ; movable: false }
            TableViewColumn{ role: "revision" ; title: "Revision" ; width: 200 ; resizable: false ; movable: false  }
            model: ListModel{
                id: tV
            }

            alternatingRowColors: true
            backgroundVisible: true
            headerVisible: true
            itemDelegate: Item {
                Text {
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
//                        color: "blue"
//                        if (enabledCheck.checked = false)
//                        color: "gray"
                    enabled: enabledCheck.checked
                    elide: styleData.elideMode
                    text: styleData.value
                } // text
            } // Item
        }// TableView
        Button {
            text: "Add row"
            x:20
            y:130
            onClicked: {
                tV.append({title: "some value",
                           author: "Another value",
                           year: "One more value",
                           revision: "uno mas"});
            }
        }

        focus: true
        Keys.onPressed: {
            if (event.key == Qt.Key_Escape) {
                Qt.quit();
                event.accepted = true;
            } //if
            if (event.key == Qt.Key_C) {
                console.log(c2);
            }
        } //Keys.onPressed
    }  // Rectangle
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when say "print information in a Qml screen from Qt"?
And you can add data to the table by appending data to the model: `libraryModel.append({title: "xxx", author: "yyy"})`

Comment: by "print info in qml" is because I have to make some querys from qt, save the information in the model and show it in qml, thnx

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model in C++, for example, by subclassing `QAbstractTableModel` and set the model property of `TableView` with it. To use it in qml you need first to make it known to qml using `setContextProperty`. For example:

```
MySubClass my_model;
engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("model_", &my_model);
```

where `engine` is an instance of the qml engine you use.

Comment: Thnks for the advice, I already create a class and expose the model, now I've another problem. I want to use the QSortFilterProxyModel to sort the info in the model, I'm not using a Widget and most of the examples I've seen refers to a TableView widget where you can sort from the view (with help from the proxymodel) but I dont know how to sort the info in a qml TableView object, I've use the command model->sort(1, Qt::AscendingOrder) when I create the proxymodel and as an action from a signal but I dont get any changes in the view

Comment: There is no simple answer. However you can try to follow the example in:   http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/04/16/qt-weekly-6-sorting-and-filtering-a-tableview/ I hope this helps

Comment: actually I already run that example in qt but it doesnt sort =(

Comment: I tried it again and it sorts correctly. To that we must press the column header.